# Value of memory changed without permission

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I have an array with 2 dimensions and when I print the data of the array the first time, the date is printed correctly, but the other times the data of array[last][i] from i = 0 to last - 1.

Apparently is a logic error, but I don't understand the reason, because I copy and paste the for statement. So... ¿C change the data?

I use `gcc -std=c99` but before that I try with C++ and `cout` statements.

[This is the output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ePrm.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned int numero_jugaderes = 11;
  unsigned int numero = numero_jugaderes - 1;

  unsigned int p_a[numero];

  float p_aya[numero][numero];

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= numero; i++) {
    p_a[i] = i;
  }

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= numero; i++) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j <= numero; j++) {
      p_aya[i][j] = (float) (p_a[i] * p_a[j]) / 100;
      printf("%f\t", p_aya[i][j]);
    }
    puts("");
  }

  puts("\n");

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= numero; i++) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j <= numero; j++) {
      printf("%f\t", p_aya[i][j]);
    }
    puts("");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is technically not a valid C++ program, since C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: @user I guess it's the opposite

Comment: As for your problem, remember that an array of X elements, have valid indexes in the range `0` to `X - 1` (inclusive). Now take a close look at your loops.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem as I see it is, you're looping over with a condition check like

```
 for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= numero; i++)
```

for an array defined as

```
unsigned int p_a[numero];
```

and you're going [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). This is essentially invalid memory access which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

C arrays have 0-based indexing, so the valid limit would be

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numero; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

An array of length numero has numero elements. Going from index 0 to numero-1. You are treating them like they have an index numero. Switch out `i <= numero` for `i < numero`. Do the same for all for loops and with j.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array declared as having `numero` elements then the valid range of indices is `[0, numero-1]`.

Thus such loops like this

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= numero; i++) {
```

used to access elements of an array with `numero` elements results in undefined behavior.